# QDeclarativeView no such file ot directory. Running QML and c++ application in qtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qml, qt-quick

What I am trying to do is test QML in qtcreator. I have newest version Qt Creator 2.8.1 based on Qt 5.1.1.

I would like to add qml to my c++ application. I tried many ways. The most reasonable look using QDeclarativeView but I can't include it.

in pro files I add

```
QT += core gui declarative
```

I tried add quick, qml aswell but then I still don't see qtquick or declarative libraries.

I can see `Qt Quick 2 UI` project in qmlViewer by go

```
Tools->external->qtquick->qmlviewer
```

When I try to build Qt Quick 2 Application(Built-in Types) I get 3x

```
"Cannot open include file "QtQuick/QQuickView" no such file or directory.
```

I want to do simple c++ application using qml thanks for any help. I read many tutorials but most of them start after build. I have problem with run application no qml code.

Comment: In hindsight, it appears a faulty installation of Qt is the most probable reason for your problems.

Comment: You were right. Problem with qt, I reinstalled and that helped!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't include it, because it's qt quick 1 and you'd like to use qt quick 2. To be able to include `QDeclarativeView` you need:

`QT += declarative`

in your `.pro` file.

Look at `QQuickView` for the qt quick 2 alternative, for which you need:

`QT += qml quick`

in your `.pro` file.

Comment: Are you sure? Can you tell me exactly in what kind of project you add this? Is it possible in GUI project? Because I tried it two version you told about and still  can;t use QQuick or QDeclarative. Do I need to put some files in my project directory? some dlls or libs?

Comment: You shouldn't needing any dlls or libs in your project directory, but you need a valid Qt install. Try copy&pasting a simple example `.qml` file, then run `qmlscene file.qml` to test if your installation works at all.